# Weird noise from laptop

Tags: lenovo-laptop, noise

I bought legion 5 15imh05h two months ago and I can hear something like scratching noise from the top middle part of the laptop. At first, I thought the right fan making the noise, but it comes from both sides and I think something in the middle part makes the sound so I can hear it from both air vents. Also when my laptop is off and I press the power button to turn it on, it makes a clicking sound and I'm almost sure that it is coming from the right part of the laptop (where w key on keyboard is located).

I recorded noise and I'm attaching it here so you can hear that. please help me if you know what the problem is.

here is the link for the recorded file:

[Recorded noise](https://www.mediafire.com/file/74zpz82gcafft2a/Noise.aac/file)

Comment: Contact Lenovo Support and have it repaired or replaced under warranty.

Comment: I would open it and see exactly where the noise is coming from. If it's from the fans, some cleaning might help.